# Hash table max function

Tags: c, function, max

I am currently working on hash tables and the double probe. I was given the following function to use but cant find the library that it is in.

```
max(1,(K/size) % size)
```

Is this function in a library or does it mean something that I have not discovered yet?

Comment: You could implement it yourself... Sometimes reinventing the wheel isn't all that bad.

Answer (score 2):

They are not defined in C library. You can create your own C library and define them or can create MACRO

MACRO can be defined as

```
      #define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
      #define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
```

Use it as follows

```
      int max = MAX(1,(K/size) % size);
```

All the calls to an MACRO get replaced with the macro expansion during the pre-processing.
So above call get replaced as,

```
      int max = (((1) > ((K/size)%size)) ? (1) : ((K/size)%size));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you just explain to me whats happening in this function?